# Django Allauth saving profile information with signup form

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

I am new in Django, I am using allauth app to create a user registration. There are some extra field I wish to have in my signup form. Not only (username, first_name, last_name) I wish to also include `info` to the registration form.
When I submit the registration form only the first_name and the last_name are saved in database, info is not saved. I guess it should be saved in Profile Model, but its not there.

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    info = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class CustomSignUpForm(Signup Form):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
    info = forms.CharField(max_length=50)

    def signup(self, request, user):
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
        user.save()
        user.profile.info = self.cleaned_data['info']
        user.profile.save()


ACCOUNT_FORM = 'signup' 'myapp.forms.CustomSignupForm'
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the `Profile` object exists for that user and you are not getting `RelatedObjectDoesNotExist` error in logs? If yes then you have to create a Profile object, in the above signup form.

```
Profile.objects.update_or_create(user=user, defaults={"info":self.cleaned_data['info']})
```